# How to select and replace multiple values of a character variable by using its starting letter with a number in r

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, data.table

This is my dataset with following values:

```
df=as.data.table(c("hello","name","age","hey","apron","street","night","soap"))

colnames(df)="V1"

Output:

  V1
1  2
2  4
3  1
4  2
5  1
6  3
7  4
8  3
```

This is done only for 1 letter i.e., a or h or s or n

```
df %>%
  mutate(V1 = case_when(startsWith(df$V1, "a") == TRUE~ '1',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "h") == TRUE~ '2',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "s") == TRUE~ '3',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "n") == TRUE~ '4'))

      V1 V2
1  hello  2
2   name  4
3    age  1
4    hey  2
5  apron  1
6 street  3
7  night  4
8   soap  3
```

I want to replace multiple values:
for example i want to replace words between range a-h by 1
Here im getting NA values instead

```
df %>%
  mutate(V2 = case_when(startsWith(df$V1, letters[1:8]) == TRUE~ '1',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "s") == TRUE~ '3',
                        startsWith(df$V1, "n") == TRUE~ '4'))

      V1   V2
1  hello <NA>
2   name    4
3    age <NA>
4    hey <NA>
5  apron <NA>
6 street    3
7  night    4
8   soap    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(V2 = case_when(substr(V1, 1, 1) %in% letters[1:8] ~ "1",
                        substr(V1, 1, 1) == "s" ~ "3",
                        substr(V1, 1, 1) == "n" ~ "4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `regex`approach

```
df%>%mutate(V2 = case_when(grepl("^[a-h].*",V1)~"1",
                           grepl("^s.*",V1)~"3",
                           grepl("^n.*",V1)~"4"))

      V1 V2
1  hello  1
2   name  4
3    age  1
4    hey  1
5  apron  1
6 street  3
7  night  4
8   soap  3
```